# How to keep np.array form after reading from a txt file?

Tags: python, numpy

```
[ 0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.69314718]
[ 0.          0.          0.          0.75        0.25        0.          0.          1.          0.69314718]
[ 0.          0.          0.          0.5         0.5         0.          0.          1.          0.69314718]
```

The `txt` file contain many np.array, how can i keep all these array form rather than string after reading?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What "array form" ?

Comment: Did you just `print` a bunch of arrays to a file? That's not a good way to store your data. It's not even guaranteed to store all of your data; after a fairly small threshold (1000 elements by default), NumPy starts abridging the printed forms of arrays.

Comment: It can only read in as a string from a txt file. After you read it in, you can put it _back_ into np.arrays

Comment: A text file does not contain np arrays. A text file contains text.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the suggestion. You're totally right and I realised it right now. Could you tell me how should we store the np.ndarray data into a file? For this one, I used kind of "for I in np.ndarray, write i" to store them, and this is why I got all these single np.array in the txt file.

Comment: @IvyGao: [`numpy.save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) or [`numpy.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) would be reasonable options.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround, though it's not necessarily ideal. You can read it in with `np.genfromtxt`, but this will give you `NaN` as the first and last element (where it is trying to read the characters `[` and `]` as float). So then you can index those out.

```
d = np.genfromtxt('file.txt')

# >>> d
# array([[ nan, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 1.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 1.  ,  nan],
#        [ nan, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.75, 0.25, 0.  , 0.  , 1.  ,  nan],
#        [ nan, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.  , 0.  , 1.  ,  nan]])

d = d[:,~np.isnan(d).all(0)]
```

Gives you:

```
>>> d
array([[0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 1.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 1.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.75, 0.25, 0.  , 0.  , 1.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.  , 0.  , 1.  ]])
```

Comment: Line #2106 (got 11 columns instead of 10) I got this error, is something wrong?

Comment: The problem here is that genfromtxt counts `0.69314718]` as a single column, rather than `0.69314718` and `]`. It's losing data on some rows, and on others, the column count mismatch causes parsing to fail entirely.